# Multi Port Fibre Channel Target with qlogic qle2462 to increase speed

Tags: solaris, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, nexenta

I have a server running Nexenta with a QLogic QLE2460 in target mode.  This works great.  My problem is that with that I only get 1 port worth of speed (4gbps) to my switch.  How can I increase the speed.  Now I will point out that I am no expert on Fibre Channel, but in networking I can hold my own.  If this was networking I could team the nics and get the speed from both.  Can I do the same with the Fibre Channel cards as targets?  I did find some documentation on using QLDirect Filter to do this for the initiators, but what about the target?  Am I better off putting the LUNs on different ports and try to get better speed by segregation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 8Gb Fibre Channel
- [MPIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_I/O)
- Enabling compression on your ZFS zvols/LUNs.

Who is consuming this data? Are you actually *seeing* bottlenecks?

And remember, it's not always about throughput. Have you taken time to understand your I/O patterns? The mix of read to write? The nature of the transfers?

Can you give more information about the setup?

Comment: MPIO is exactly what I needed.  On one hand you point out some great things that I should check on, however the truth is that this is a newer setup.  The servers will quickly grow to over 40 however and I suspect a 4gbps setup will not work during heavy load times.  I do have several drive controllers to spread the load, but a single port FC HBA.  I was trying to solve this problem before it became one.  I found this great article once I knew what to look for... again thanks... http://info.nexenta.com/rs/nexenta/images/doc_3.1_target-fc-and-host-multipathing.pdf